# Dealing with hash in PHP json object

Tags: php, json

I have a json object that follows the following structure:

$foo->bar['1']->#foobar

The hash is causing it to fail, how do I get the value of #foobar?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the curly brace syntax:

```
$foo->bar['1']->{'#foobar'}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use PHP's [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), pass `true` as the second variable, that will return an associative array, those are easier to deal with in such cases.

Comment: +1 actually answers a different question that I needed the answer to.